# Unable to open the excel file after base64 encoded and sent as attachment

Tags: java, excel, base64

I am trying to encode the excel file of 50MB into base64 and write to byteArrayOutputStream in java. I used the below code

```
        ByteArrayOutputStream base = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new Base64OutputStream(base));
        oos.writeObject(filebytes);
        postData.write(base.toByteArray());
        oos.close();
        base.close();
```

The above code works fine for excel of 10 mb but when I send excel of more than 50 mb I am unable to open the excel once it is attached to the target system

Answer (score 0):

The call to `postData.write` is before close so it could send an incomplete stream, it should be after.

```
oos.close();
postData.write(base.toByteArray());
```

It is unclear as to why you send the data using `ObjectOutputStream` if you already have the data as `byte[] filebytes`, as you could send `byte[]` directly. Obviously your sender/receiver code needs compatible encode/decode mechanism at each side if you switched from `ObjectOutputStream` to `byte[]`.

Note also that using in-memory copies of large streams may risk `OutOfMemoryError` if the size of your Excel files increase, it is better to send large files as a stream not one huge chunk.